# how to use voodoo camera tracker?

Tags: computer-vision

I have the voodoo camera tracker software which takes a video as an input and gives ouput in the following format:

```
# Text export 
# created by voodoo camera tracker - www.digilab.uni-hannover.de
# Creation date: Mon Feb 28 18:41:56 2011
# The camera (one line per frame) 
#
# Description of the CAHV camera model:
# -------------
# (Cx, Cy, Cz)    : CameraPosition [mm]
# (Ax, Ay, Az)    : RotationAxis2  [unit vector]
# (Hx, Hy, Hz)    : RotationAxis0 [pel] (including FocalLength, PixelSizeX, and Principal Point offset) 
# (Vx, Vy, Vz)    : RotationAxis1 [pel] (including FocalLength, PixelSizeY, and Principal Point offset) 
# (K3, K5)        : Radialdistortion;   K3 [1/(mm)^2]   K5 [1/(mm)^4]
# (sx, sy)        : PixelSize   [mm/pel]
# (Width, Height) : ImageSize   [pel]
# -------------
# (ppx, ppy)      : Principal Point offset [pel]
# f               : Focal Length [mm]
# fov             : Horizontal Field of View [degree] = (2*atan(0.5*Width*sx/f)*180/PI;
# (H0x, H0y, H0z) : RotationAxis0 [unit vector]
# (V0x, V0y, V0z) : RotationAxis1 [unit vector]
# -------------
# (x, y)          : image coordinates [pel]
# (X, Y, Z)       : 3D coordinates [mm]
# -------------
# Projection of 3D coordinates in the camera image:
#  [ x' ] =  [ Hx Hy Hz ] [ 1 0 0 -Cx] [ X ]
#  [ y' ] =  [ Vx Vy Vz ] [ 0 1 0 -Cy] [ Y ]
#  [ z' ] =  [ Ax Ay Az ] [ 0 0 1 -Cz] [ Z ]
#                                      [ 1 ]
# or 
#  [ x' ] =  [f/sx 0    ppx] [ H0x H0y H0z ] [ 1 0 0 -Cx] [ X ]
#  [ y' ] =  [0    f/sy ppy] [ V0x V0y V0z ] [ 0 1 0 -Cy] [ Y ]
#  [ z' ] =  [0    0    1  ] [ Ax  Ay  Az  ] [ 0 0 1 -Cz] [ Z ]
#                                                         [ 1 ]
# then x = x'/z' and y = y'/z' , if the origin of the image coordinates is in the center of the image
# or x = x'/z' + 0.5*(Width-1) and y = y'/z' + 0.5*(Height-1) , if the origin of the image coordinates is in the upper left corner
# -------------
# Cx Cy Cz Ax Ay Az Hx Hy Hz Vx Vy Vz K3 K5 sx sy Width Height ppx ppy f fov H0x H0y H0z V0x V0y V0z
```

Now this is a CAHV camera model which gives  the values for every frame. I want to know how to extract the camera parameters like translation, rotation, zoom from this output??
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

[This link gives us the details how to use the tracker.](http://www.digilab.uni-hannover.de/docs/manual.html#usage)

As you can see, the last step says:: Export the estimated camera parameters to the 3D animation package. So I exported into a Maya Script file, and then I used Notepad++ to open the file which gave the details regarding the camera parameters for each frame.